# Packages skipped because of dependency problems

Tags: yum, upgrade, dependencies, patch

While patching is going on a CentOS system, I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then the patching stopped. When I tried to patch again, it showed dependency error and I couldn't patch the remaining patches.

I got this error

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    kernel-devel-3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 from centos7-x86_64-updates
    1:make-3.82-24.el7.x86_64 from centos7-x86_64
    systemtap-4.0-10.el7_7.x86_64 from centos7-x86_64-updates
    systemtap-client-4.0-10.el7_7.x86_64 from centos7-x86_64-updates
    systemtap-devel-4.0-10.el7_7.x86_64 from centos7-x86_64-updates

Error: Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root cause is something else and multilib version checking is just pointing out that there is a problem.
```

Comment: What error message do you get? What have you tried?

Comment: Please show us the output of the command were the error is present

Comment: Please edit your question to include details, don't use the comments for that.